# Is there any way to set custom headers and make a get request in jsp page without ajax

Tags: ajax, spring, servlets

Is there any way to redirect to spring controller from a jsp page with custom headers. 
I don't want to do a GET/POST request using jquery ajax.
I want to do a complete redirect to another page..
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe. Note: Changing the headers isn't possible if your JSP has written something, so the "redirection" needs to be the first thing on the page.

What you can do is use `jsp:include` to include another page. If your JSP doesn't output anything else, that will work very much like a redirect. You can use

```
<%if(...){%>
    <jsp:include ...>
<%}else{%>
    ...no redirect...
<%}%>`
```

to create alternatives to make sure nothing is written to the output.

The next step is then to get the controller bean from Spring and call the methods directly. Note that you'll have to replicate a bunch of Spring's conveniences (like converting the result of the method into bytes sent to the browser). But Spring isn't doing any magic; eventually everything is Java code somewhere which you just have to call manually.

Comment: Thanks. I got that jsp:include can be used to redirect if nothing else is written in output. However bigger question is how do i set the custom header. Could you help me with some code for that, because that's the main requirement calling redirect with custom header say eg : "test header". I need to pass header because the URL i am calling requires that "test header" as a mandatory argument.

Comment: You can use `response.setHeader()` to modify the header. But you must to this before you do anything else, i.e. the first characters in the JSP must be: `<%response.setHeader(`. If there is even a single space or a blank line before that, the JSP compiler will write something to the response and you can't be 100% sure that the new header can be sent to the browser.